# No mxtics in logscale with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am having troubles making Gnuplot show the intemediate tics (mxtics) in a log scale. I have looked up similar topics, but none of the answers work for me. Please find enclosed a minimal working example,

```
set size 1,1
set origin 0,0

unset xtics
set yrange [-1:1]
set xrange [1e-6:2]


set mxtics 10
set logscale x
set format x ""
set xtics 1, 1e-2
set xtics 1e-4, 1e-6
set xtics add ("10^{-4}" 1e-4,"10^{-2}" 1e-2,  "1" 1) offset 0,0
set xtics nomirror

set format y ""
unset ytics

p 0.0
```

which provides the following output, with no mxtics:
[image]

I would like to have 10 mxtics per decade, i.e., one at 10^{-2}, one at 2 10^{-2}, ..., one at 9 10^{-2}. Do you know how to do that? I have tried changing the order of the command lines, but it didn't work.

FYI, here is the Gnuplot version that I am using:

```
$ gnuplot 

    G N U P L O T
    Version 5.2 patchlevel 2    last modified 2017-11-15
```

EDIT: The following is tentative way to make this work:

```
set xrange [1e-6:1]
set yrange [-1:1]

set logscale x
set format x "10^{%T}"
set xtics add ("" 1e-3, "" 1e-5, "" 1e-1)
set mxtics 10
set xtics nomirror

set format y ""
unset ytics
unset ylabel

p 0 w l lw 2 linecolor rgb "black" noti
```

and it produces the output [image] However, this does not work if I `set term epslatex`, which is the terminal that I ultimately want to use.

In fact, if I run the same script with epslatex terminal, the xtics at 10^{-3}, ... are not removed.

Comment: strange, if I look into the generated .tex file with a text-editor, I only see 10^{-4} and 10^{-2}

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying a bit too complicated. Wouldn't the following do what you want or do you want something special and different?

**Code:**

```
### log tics and mtics
reset session

set xrange[1e-6:2]
set logscale x
set format x "10^{%T}"
set mxtics 10
set grid xtics,mxtics lt -1, lt 0
set xtics add ("" 1e-6, "" 1e-5, "" 1e-3, "" 1e-1, "1" 1)
plot x
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I would like to make a plot where I set the (main) xtics at arbitrary positions, i.e., at 10^{-2} and 10^{-4}, not at 10^{-1}, 10^{-2}, 10^{-3}, see the original post. Do you know how to achieve this?

Comment: well, then "remove" the tics you don't want e.g. with `set xtics add ("" 1e-6)`. Code modified.

Comment: That could work thank you. In fact, it works if I use x11 terminal, but not if I use epslatex terminal, see the edit to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

As for me, the `epslatex` output produced from your edit looks fine for me, it only contains the major xtics labeled at 10^-6, 10^-4, 10^-2 and 10^-0. Therefore this code is working perfectly (I only changed the xtics format to math so that latex doesn't complain):

```
set term epslatex standalone
set out "logtics.tex"
set xrange [1e-6:1]
set yrange [-1:1]

set logscale x
set format x "$10^{%T}$"
set xtics add ("" 1e-3, "" 1e-5, "" 1e-1)
set mxtics 10
set xtics nomirror

set format y ""
unset ytics
unset ylabel

p x w l lw 2 linecolor rgb "black" noti
unset out
unset term
```

[image: Screenshot from resulting pdf]

I am using gnuplot 5.3, maybe there was some kind of bugfix in-between…

If that is not helping you, did you consider switching to `cairolatex` terminal? It has the same purpose, but it overcomes the troubles of converting eps to pdf prior to inclusion in pdflatex.